# Trouble w/ Form Processing using jQuery + PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I'm having the hardest time getting a simple form to process using jQuery and PHP. I've tried getting the data via `$_POST`, `$_GET`, and `$_REQUEST` but I guess I'm missing a simple line of code or a complete process altogether.

### app.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sucMsg').hide();
    $('#errMsg').hide();
    $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        alert(form.serialize());
        $.ajax(form.attr('action'), {
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                form.remove();
                $('#sucMsg').append(result);
                $('#sucMsg').fadeIn();
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(thrownError);
                $('#errMsg').append(thrownError);
                $('#errMsg').fadeIn();
            }

        });
    });
});
```

### formProcess.php

```
<?php
    if ($_POST) {
        echo "Posted something.";
    } elseif ($_GET) {
        echo "Getted something.";
    } else {
        echo "Nothing is working...";
    }
    $tagNumberPost = $_POST['inputTagNumber'];
    $pricePost = $_POST['inputPrice'];
    $makePost = $_POST['inputMake'];

    $tagNumberRequest = $_REQUEST['inputTagNumber'];
    $priceRequest = $_REQUEST['inputPrice'];
    $makeRequest = $_REQUEST['inputMake'];

    if (isset($_REQUEST['inputTagNumber'])) {
        echo '$_REQUEST works...\n';
    } elseif (isset($_POST['inputTagNumber'])) {
        echo '$_POST works...\n';
    } elseif (isset($_GET['inputTagNumber'])) {
        echo '$_GET works...\n';
    } else {
        echo "Nothing is working...";
    }

    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Tag number: " . $tagNumber . "<br/>\n";
    echo "Make: ".$makePost . "<br/>\n";
    echo "Price: " . $pricePost . "<br/>\n";
?>
```

What I'm expecting to get back is the all the `echo`'s in my `formProcess.php` to print out in my `#sucMsg` div.

Comment: so whats the real problem here?

Comment: What do you see in your alert box on form submit? Add it to the question.

Comment: What does `form.attr('action')` return? Are you sure that you're hitting the url of `formPrcoess.php`?

Comment: I see the serialized data of the input boxes @sealocal.

Comment: Sorry, the `form.attr('action')` points to `formProcess.php`. I am sure I'm hitting the url of `formProcess.php` because the `echo` calls appear in my `result` and are `.append`ed to my `#sucMsg` and then faded in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you setting your `contentType:` as `application/json`? You do not need that. Remove it.

```
contentType: 'application/json', // remove this line
```

Just leave it to its default as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` if your request is POST.

And in your PHP, `$tagNumber` is undefined.

```
if (isset(
    $_POST['inputTagNumber'], 
    $_POST['inputTagNumber'],
    $_POST['inputMake'],
)) {

    $tagNumber = $_POST['inputTagNumber']; // define tagNumber
    $pricePost = $_POST['inputPrice'];
    $makePost = $_POST['inputMake'];

    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Tag number: " . $tagNumber . "<br/>\n";
    echo "Make: ".$makePost . "<br/>\n";
    echo "Price: " . $pricePost . "<br/>\n";

}
```

Comment: @gh0st because you're sending it as `application/json` which wouldn't make sense. Your sending it as a form url encoded not json. So that your `$_POST` values are populated.

Comment: Ok so `contentType` defines what is being sent in the ajax method and dataType defines what is returned. I think I understand now. I was following a tutorial and was under the impression that `contentType:json` was what was being sent once I `serialize`d.

Comment: @gh0st yes, thats basically it. your sending a form post, so setting it to application/json is unneeded. glad this helped